# Why is this generated ruby regex not working in the actual code?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I found a [site](http://txt2re.com/) where I can generate ruby regex.
So basically you enter the text and click the part you want to extract:

[image]

So I tried it:

```
product.css('.crAvgStars .swSprite span').text[/([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])/, 1]
```

To get the `4.4` but got `nil` instead.

Is the regex not working or I placed it in an incorrect way?

Comment: What is `product.css('.crAvgStars .swSprite span').text`?

Comment: The site you linked has for some reason escaped the `\ ` to `\\ ` for Ruby syntax. That may be how it is displayed as a `String`, but is not how you use it. Just change all the double `\\ ` to `\ `

Comment: A star and a downvote and a close? Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
s = "4.4 out of 5 stars"
p s[/([+-]?\d*\.\d+)(?![-+0-9\.])/]
# >> "4.4"
```

You can find this way[**`Regexp.new`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-new):

```
Regexp.new('([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])')
# => /([+-]?\d*\.\d+)(?![-+0-9\.])/
```

Comment: Thanks, worked. So the generator doesn't produce correct regex? Or how should I modify the generated regex so it works? (seems like the generator is adding additional `//`?)

Comment: Try always on Rubular..Its better.

Comment: but Rubular doesn't let you click the section you want to fetch? You have to write your own regex?

Comment: @alexchenco humm that's true.. :)

Comment: So what basically happened with the regex I posted? It had extra `//`s? How do I know which I should remove in the future?

Comment: Don't rely on some code to generate the regular expression for you. Code will fail miserably when it gets slightly complex.  Instead, learn to write them yourself.